# Python's namespace equivalent for dict.get()

Tags: python, namespaces

Right now I have the following code in my project:

```
if keyword in sample_namespace:
    return sample_namespace[keyword]
else:
    return None
```

Namespace is build dynamically from plugins content.

If it were an dictionary, and not a namespace, I could simply do sample_dict.get(keyword), to get the same functionality. Is there any way how to do this with namespaces while achieving the same neatness?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`getattr`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
return getattr(sample_namespace,keyword,None)
```

Alternatively, if you're using the term `namespace`, `vars(namespace)` will return a dictionary which is a representation of the namespace.